# How to make Curl request for USPS django python

Tags: python, django, curl, usps

I am working on USPS API for tracking packages i want to make curl request for tracking package.

This is what i found on USPS API documentation for tracking package.

> ```
> > http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=<TrackFieldRequest
> > USERID="xxxxxxxxxx"> <TrackID ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXX">  </TrackID> 
> > 
> > </TrackFieldRequest>
> ```

Now i am trying to make curl request in django this is what i am doing but it does not working.Is this a right way to parse xml/url in django.

```
def get_tracking_status(self):
        try:
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
            xml = "<TrackFieldRequest USERID='xxxxxxxxxx'><TrackID ID='XXXXXXXXXXXXX'></TrackID></TrackFieldRequest>"
            requests.post("http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll?API=TrackV2", headers=headers, data=xml)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request you make via CURL has two query parameters: API, whose value is "TrackV2", and XML, whose value is the xml blob. You should just do the same with requests:

```
requests.get("http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll", data={'API': 'TrackV2', 'XML': xml}, headers=headers)
```

Note also it appears to be a GET, not a POST.